# How to change console title?

Tags: command-line

on windows I have command

> title new title name

is it possible on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 10.04 go to Edit > Profile Preferences and select the "Title and Command" tab and change:

**Initial title: any_title_you_like**

**When title commands set their own titles: Keep initial title**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use *xtitle* (not installed by default):

```
xtitle new title name
```

Comment: That did not work on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Works here on 10.04 after installing xtitle

Comment: will it work with lxterminal?

Comment: I guess so. It uses a control sequence introduced by xterm and works with most terminal emulators I used so far - but I've never used lxterminal so I don't know for sure.

Comment: This is the one I want but it doesn't seem to be working, at least under 11.04 - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/93185/xtitle-not-changing-title-in-ubuntu-11-04

Comment: It worked for me in Gnome Terminal; except if I first manually changed the title using the menu, it did not work.

Comment: Doesn't work on QQ or RR :(

Comment: Does work with LXTerminal 0.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Just click Terminal > Set Title in your *Terminal*.

Answer (score 1):

- Assuming that by title you mean the text shown in the Titlebar: If you use the gnome-terminal, you can goto Menu > Terminal > Title. It will ask you to set the title for the terminal. However, the name will be lost after you close the terminal.
- Assuming you want to change the `name@hosts:~$` bit because of a mis-spelling. Well, thats a wee lil' bit complicated. There are three parts to it, your username, your hostname, and the current directory. You can change the username by executing

  `usermod --login NewUserName`

  You can change the hostname by editing the contents of the `/etc/hostname`. Just type

  `sudo nano --nonewlines /etc/hostname`

  And third, your current directory environment variable will keep changing according to the well, current directory :p