# xtitle not changing title in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, gnome-terminal, titlebar

I'm trying to find a way to quickly change the title of a Gnome Terminal 2.32.1 window since I have quite a few open and I'm editing different files in each, using a compiler in one, tailing log files in others and so forth. Hence it's a pain looking for the window I want when they all say `pax@pax-desktop:~`.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39199/how-to-change-console-title) led me to try `xtitle` but, for some reason it's not actually changing the title.

Executing `xtitle xyzzy` results in no visible feedback but piping it through `od` confirms it's outputting an escape sequence (which I'm *assuming* is correct, though I haven't checked in detail):

```
pax@pax-desktop:~/porn_dir$ xtitle xyzzy | od -xcb
0000000    5d1b    3b32    7978    7a7a    0779    5d1b    3b31    7978
        033   ]   2   ;   x   y   z   z   y  \a 033   ]   1   ;   x   y
        033 135 062 073 170 171 172 172 171 007 033 135 061 073 170 171
0000020    7a7a    0779
          z   z   y  \a
        172 172 171 007
0000024
```

I can go into the menu `Terminal | Set Title` and change it okay from there but I would much prefer a command-line solution since I can do it automatically (such as create a `vi` alias which sets the title to `vi filename` before running the editor and resets it on exit).

In the profile preferences, the initial title is set to `Terminal` and the `When terminal commands set their own titles` is set to `Replace initial title`. There's also only the one profile `Default` which is the one I'm using.

Comment: Wow, a whole hour and no answers yet. On SO, I would have had about ten answers by now along with a lively debate going on in the comments, some questioning my sanity and/or parentage. Oh well, guess I'll need to learn some patience :-) In any case, I've sorted it now, see below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out `xtitle` is working fine and changing the title. However, there's a section in the default `.bashrc` as follows:

```
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

which sets the prompt up so that it changes the title back to the usual value every time it asks the user for input.

By commenting the `PS1=...` line above out, the title remains set to whatever you choose.

This has the side effect of not updating the current `user@host` status for all terminals.  To selectively enable this for just the current shell, before running `xtitle` use:

```
export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

(Remember, you must source this in the terminal, not call/source from a script!)

Comment: Not working in Ubuntu 13.10: 
$ export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ ' 
$ xtitle TEST 
$ xtermcontrol --get-title 
Terminal 
$ xtermcontrol --title=TEST 
$ xtermcontrol --get-title 
Terminal 
EDIT: both outputs of `xtermcontrol --get-title` were "Terminal" and so is shown in the unity launcher as a tooltip. However, the tab title is set to current pwd

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gnome Terminal, also check that in `Edit` -> `Profile Preferences` -> `Title and Command` you have the `When terminal commands set their own titles` option set to `Replace initial title` (the default).